# Chinese L visa expiration?

Tags: visas, china, tourist-visas, visa-expiration

So I am a US citizen and I have a Chinese L visa for multiple entries that was issued in June 2012, the enter before date was June 2013. I am planning to travel to China in a month (August) and was wondering if my visa is still valid or I should apply for a new one. Thanks!

Comment: I can stand corrected on this, but I believe the "Enter Before" date is the expiration date of the visa. Have you miskeyed the dates or is it actually 4 years ago? Not the official source, but [take a look at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_China).

Comment: Thanks for reply, the dates are correct, I am not sure if my visa is last for 10 years or have expired already.

Comment: Note that "visa" is a perfectly ordinary word. It's not an acronym, so it never needs to be written in all caps.

Comment: I don't think China typically issued 10 year visas to Americans before 2014. I think you have a 1 year visa that is now expired.

Comment: @Dennis why not make this an answer? It is correct, OP's visa is expired and that's it. Ping me and I'll +1 immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your visa is expired and you should apply for a new one.**

The [enter before-date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_China#Validity.2C_number_of_entries_and_duration_of_each_stay_of_Chinese_visas) is what comes closest to the expire date, the meaning, quite obviously being that you must enter before the date given.
In a comment you mention the 10 year visa. While such a visa is available to US citizens, the respective agreement has only been put up in [November 2014](http://www.reuters.com/article/us-china-usa-visas-idUSKCN0IU0Q020141110) so we can exclude that your visa issued in 2012 is a 10 year visa. You can recognize a [Chinese 10 year visa](https://i1.wp.com/www.lindalivinginchina.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/10year.jpg) from the issue-date to the enter before-date spanning 10 years.